# ASP.Net UTF-8 dont display correctly after changing culture in page directive

Tags: asp.net, culture, arabic, utf

i designed an export to excel page that uses the following code

[image]

the data is displayed in grid view and the date format is displayed as M/d/yyyy
so i added the culture en-GB to page directive to display the date as d/M/yyyy

[image]

the date now displays correctly d/M/yyyy, and the utf-8 also display correctly in gridview.

however once i export to excel the utf-8 appears scrambled

when ever i remove the culture from page directives, names display correctly, however i face again the M/d/yyyy issue.

My question is: is there a way to display date as d/M/yyyy and at the same time reading correct utf-8

any ideas will be appreciated

Comment: Do you specify the encoding type somewhere (like UTF-8) ?

Comment: If you put `Response.AddHeader...` and `Response.ContentType...` in comments, does your browser show the Arabic names?

Comment: Change the Response.ContentType to 'text/html'. I'm not proposing this as an answer. I'm trying to find out if the problem is with Excel or the data that's being sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is what you should do to solve your issue

1-remove culture settings from page directive
this will output correct display of arabic names in excel, right?

2-to solve the date issue do the following in the gridview aspx code

```
AutoGenerateColumns="false"
```

the previous piece of code should be inserted in the , it will prevent column auto-generation

now you need to generate columns manually, use the following code as example

```
<Columns> 
<asp:BoundField DataField="EmployeeName" HeaderText="Name" /> 
<asp:BoundField DataField="Gender" HeaderText="Gender" /> 
<asp:BoundField DataField="DOB" DataFormatString="{0:d/M/yyyy}" HeaderText="DOB" /> 
</Columns>
```